# Parse multiple nested file in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having this file, this file is a sample result form a elastic search query.

```
[{'key': 'hkdshkdsd',
  'doc_count': 1851,
  'aggs_fs': {'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
   'sum_other_doc_count': 697,
   'buckets': [{'key': 'jdsjodsjod',
     'doc_count': 113,
     'agg_date': {'buckets': [{'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T14:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599487200000,
        'doc_count': 20,
        'agg_ave': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T15:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599490800000,
        'doc_count': 19,
        'agg_ave': {'value': 40.22999954223633},
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T16:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599494400000,
        'doc_count': 27,
        'agg_ave': {'value': 40.22999954223633},
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T17:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599498000000,
        'doc_count': 20,
        'agg_ave': {'value': 40.22999954223633},
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T18:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599501600000,
        'doc_count': 23,
        'agg_ave': {'value': 40.22999954223633},
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T19:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599505200000,
        'doc_count': 4,
        'agg_ave': {'value': 40.22999954223633},
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T20:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599508800000,
        'doc_count': 0,
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T21:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599512400000,
        'doc_count': 0,
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T22:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599516000000,
        'doc_count': 0,
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-07T23:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599519600000,
        'doc_count': 0,
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-08T00:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599523200000,
        'doc_count': 0,
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-08T01:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599526800000,
        'doc_count': 0,
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}},
       {'key_as_string': '2020-09-08T02:00:00.000Z',
        'key': 1599530400000,
        'doc_count': 0,
        'aggs_ma': {'value': 40.22999954223633}}]}}]}}]
```

I need to convert this file in a pandas DataFrame, I tried to use `json_normalize`, but seems it is just normalizing the first key and when the first key is normalized and want to keep normalizing what happens is that return me an error.

Does somebody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Given the nested nature of the data, please provide an example of what you'd like the DataFrame to look like.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
dfs = []
for i in your_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(i, orient='index')
    # Use pd.DataFrame.from_dict(i, orient='index').T may be
    dfs.append(dfs)

full_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

It just made life easier than `json_normalize`

Comment: @ScottUrbina please give an expected output. The code will need some changes.